# Error in SQL-Syntax..Showing just 3 instead of 4 rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a SQL-Query what should return 4 rows.. But it just returns 3 rows..

My Tables are looking like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/10bog.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BuvD.png

Here's my Syntax:

```
SELECT gruppe
FROM gruppen
WHERE gruppe LIKE '%Vormittag%'
AND gruppe_id NOT IN (SELECT gruppe_id
                      FROM daten
                      GROUP BY gruppe_id
                      HAVING COUNT(gruppe_id) >= 15)
ORDER BY gruppe ASC;
```

I should get a list of 4 Groups..But i just get this 3:

```
"Gruppe 2 | Vormittag"

"Gruppe 3 | Vormittag"

"Gruppe 4 | Vormittag"
```

Where's the Problem that hides the first one?

Comment: Without sample data that query is not helping much

Comment: maybe gruppe 1 have count >= 15 ?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't post real data.

Comment: @DonCallisto they dont even have a count, cause there's no User (Table: "Daten") in a Group..

Comment: @BenjaminSchurtenberger: what are you talking about? Do you know what second part of your query does?

Comment: @DonCallisto Yes i know it, but i wonder why i get just Group 2,3 and 4..Cause the Max. User-Limit of a group is set to 15..

Comment: @BenjaminSchurtenberger: could you explain what second part (let's call it "inner select") does, please?

Comment: @DonCallisto yeah, second part gets all the gruppe_id's where are 15 people in the group, so the id of the full groups wont be used in the "first" query..

Comment: @BenjaminSchurtenberger: you said that there aren't users for gruppe 1, right? So why do you expect that second query return - among others - 1 as gruppe id?

Comment: @DonCallisto There's not an only user registered for a group.. Theres just 1 user and this one has no group.. So all 4 groups have the same count of users: 0.. so i wonder why there are just 3 displayed..

Comment: @BenjaminSchurtenberger: could you split the query and show us the result of "inner select" please (or, better, could you also include the count(id) into select result?)

Comment: @DonCallisto http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3729/9s6tsfcl_png.htm

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT G.gruppe
FROM gruppen G
WHERE G.gruppe LIKE '%Vormittag%'
   AND G.gruppe_id NOT IN (SELECT D.gruppe_id
                      FROM daten D
                      WHERE D.gruppe_id IS NOT NULL
                      GROUP BY D.gruppe_id
                      HAVING COUNT(D.gruppe_id) >= 15)
ORDER BY G.gruppe ASC
```

I just added aliases for the tables in order to avoid conflict between columns with the same name.

Instead of that, your query seems to be correct!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but still returns just group 2,3 & 4

Comment: If there is no entry in your table [daten], this query should return every rows of the table [gruppe] with 'Vormittag' in the name

Comment: I updated my answer to include the solution you marked. The use of aliases still is a good practice to improve readability and avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `WHERE` clause to your inner select:

```
WHERE gruppe_id IS NOT NULL
```

You can check fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/067d6/11/0).

Additional information about this behavior you can find [here](http://blog.9minutesnooze.com/sql-not-in-subquery-null/).